# Which champions can jungle effectively in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the characteristics that a champion should have to jungle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58807/what-are-the-characteristics-that-a-champion-should-have-to-jungle)

Which champions can solo in the jungle and keep their levels up to those in lane?  I know Warwick of course, and I've seen Shaco and Udyr do okay.  What others work well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It highly depends on how you build the champion, but I've seen:

- Tryndamere (start with Agility Pot)
- Xin Shao (start with agility Pot)
- Amumumu
- Olaf

More often than not succeed as junglers. There are other heroes who *can* jungle, but these are particularly adept at it.

Comment: This answer feels outdated already. Irelia is a competent jungler, as well as Nunu.

Comment: @Danixd This answer is not outdated, because the 4 champions stated are still competent junglers. If the answer had included, say, Evelyn, who has been nerfed so that she cannot jungle effectively, your comment might have more merit.

Comment: Well Nunu is a lot more competent at jungling than Amumu and Irelia a lot more competanat than Tryndamere!

Answer (score 4):

Stonewall's tier list is probably a good resource to go by:

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=325897

```
Tier 1 – Udyr, Lee Sin, Trundle, Nocturne, Fiddlesticks, Cho Gath, Skarner
Tier 2 – Warwick, Riven, Shaco, Jarvan, Nunu, Xin Zhao, Amumu, Gangplank, Maokai, 
Tier 3 – Master Yi, Olaf, Malphite, Tryndamere, Shen, Yorick, Rammus, Gragas
Tier 4 – Alistar, Akali, Graves, Sion, Galio, Irelia, Kayle, Renekton, Soraka, Nasus
Tier 5 – Mordekaiser, Karthus, Pantheon, Taric, Wukong, Jax, Evelynn, Orianna, Talon
```

Anything under Tier 3 should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddlesticks can jungle if you get Drain Life as your first skill instead of the traditional Dark Wind. I wouldn't recommend it though as he's much better at lane control.

Warwick too with his natural life steal as you mentioned, though he's much more prone to getting jungle-ganked.

Comment: +1 for mentioning fiddle, but I don't agree that he's better in lane.  Fiddle's real strength comes from his ult, which is best used from hding.  The jungle keeps him off the radar, making his ganks much more powerful.

Comment: @Toast Yeah this answer was made over a year ago, back when the game was much different. I would agree with you now.

Comment: My bad; I see it got resurrected, but the question itself is quite old.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of champions can jungle. Most often : warwick, udyr, fiddlesticks, amumu, yi.
You can also see olaf, akali, mundo.

The thing is that most of the champions can jungle at lvl 1, but the question is : how fast ?

Try & make your choice !

Answer (score 1):

Also IMO, **Mordekaiser**, because he can Farms quickly, and his skills provide shield

Answer (score 1):

Shaco can.  And he does it really well.

Comment: What characteristics/abilities make him good at jungling?

Answer (score 1):

Top junglers as of 01 Nov 2011:

- Lee Sin (often banned, goes from jungle to late game carry, super mobile and somewhat tanky)
- Udyr (Phoenix Udyr clears jungle so fast and is just overall useful to the team)
- Nocturne (awesome ganks, useful in teamfights later on)
- Trundle (easy clears, Pillar of Filth is one of the best spells in the game, very cool Ult)
- Gangplank (it's Gangplank, he can do a little bit of everything, and is useful in many ways)

There are some upcoming junglers that might gain more popularity, namely Riven (very strong ganks, scales insanely with free farm from jungle) and Skarner (great buffs recently, some of the best stats in the game, great ganks).

Shaco is fun, as always and has probably the nastiest lvl 2 gank in the game. Nunu, Olaf, Warwick, and Trynd can all jungle fine but aren't top tier from what I can tell.

**The real badass jungler is Rammus**.  His ganks are nuts and you get a great AD tank that clears the jungle with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Evelynn jungling as of late.  Master Yi is also a viable jungler with the right set up; he's not meant to be a jungler though.

Sivir can jungle, but I wouldn't recommend it as a primary means of leveling.  She's more of an "I'm running through the jungle to get somewhere faster, so I'm going to take a few seconds and annihilate these hapless creatures" type of gal.

Answer (score 0):

Morgana can jungle ;)
http://leaguecraft.com/strategies/guide/7379-morgana-the-roaming-jungle-queen.xhtml